# why is the class attribute not being removed from using sanitize here?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to strip attributes from some html fragments using the sanitize method. I am trying via but it keeps the class intact:

```
=>  ActionController::Base.helpers.sanitize("hello <p class='MsoNormal'>here</p> i am", tags: %w(strong b br p ul li em u))
=> "hello <p class=\"MsoNormal\">here</p> i am"
```

Any idea on how to get the class attribute to be stripped out?

Comment: `sanitize(str, attributes: [])` https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html

Comment: looks like to remove class you need to delete from built-in allowed attributes. so in an initializer `ActionView::Base.sanitized_allowed_attributes.delete("class")`. a bit cryptic